# SymmetricDS: support for different database stucture and transectional property

Tags: database-replication, symmetricds

I am confused about some property of SymmetricDs. i.e.

1. If the remote and the central database have different database structure (not different database like mysql, oracle etc.), how can we manage it? For example, if the remote database have two relational table 'A' and 'B', and the central database have only one table 'C' to hold both data of remote table 'A' and 'B' of remote database, how can we manage it ? As we can't define a same trigger on two different table.
2. If the remote application have a transactional block for any action, so that rows of data from different table may reflect the change as a unit, how can SymmetricDS can manage it ? They wrote about transactional attribute in their user guide, but I didn't get it.

Can anyone give me any idea about this ? Also you can suggest me any other open source tool for database synchronization and replication.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use lookup table feature
2. SymmetricDs will sync only committed data, enclosed in batches